# Python Script Nor Running In PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, django, uwsgi, wsgi, pythonanywhere

I am working on a Django project. It includes a functionality in which when admin clicks on a certain button, it runs a Python script and redirect it to some other page after complete process. Before hosting, it was working fine. Now that I hosted it here, the script doesn't run at all. It just redirects to another page without providing any error. Why's that? Also, my script includes chromedriver, in case it has anything to do with it.

Kindly help me.

This might be the error. Why doesn't it recognize it?

**Code**

```
out = run([sys.executable, '//home//maisum279//traffic//traffic//trafficapp//traffic.py', "--domain", url, "--threads", '5', "--max-clicks", maximum, "--min-clicks", minimum, "--stay", stay, "--requests", requests])
```

**Server Log**

```
2020-09-21 11:05:02 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi: unrecognized option '--domain' 
2020-09-21 11:05:02 getopt_long() error
```

The script is in Python, but now it seems to be running with uswgi. What can I do make it work? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Since PythonAnywhere is apparently running things with uWSGI, which embeds Python, `sys.executable` is `uwsgi` and not `python3`.

You may want to try e.g. `['/usr/bin/env', 'python3', ...]` instead of relying on `sys.executable`.

Comment: I think it's working since I got a different error now which is `driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)#012TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'` even though it was working fine before hosting. Can you guide me?

Comment: To run Chrome on PythonAnywhere you need to have some beta features enabled on your account. Write to support@pythonanywhere.com and ask for it.